# Is an if statement without brackets faster?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic

I recently did a code test for a company that is using C (and sort of C++) to write their own language. I was somewhat appalled at all the if statements that were in the code that they sent me that had no brackets. Initially I just thought they were hacks but then I was wondering if they did it that way because it is actually (minimally) faster. Also, if anyone has seen the bit of code that was the cause of the [security breach in iOS](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/02/extremely-critical-crypto-flaw-in-ios-may-also-affect-fully-patched-macs/) recently, you'll note that curly braces would have thwarted the bug. Are they writing for speed as well?

This question is open to any C (syntax) type language as I imagine there could be some differences.

Comment: @JasonC - That's part of why I'm asking the question. I don't think there would be any speed penalty associated with a curly bracket but why would Apple and another company that is building a language want to skip the curly brackets in their code? Just programmer laziness? Generally speaking more code means slower code so I was wondering if that extended to curly brackets. For the record, I don't 'think' it does.

Comment: Style preference, albeit a style that can be prone to mistakes.

Comment: Also, "more code" does not imply "slower code", certainly not in a general case. A binary search, for example, is generally more code than a brute force search. Do not make the mistake of associating code complexity/verbosity with higher level performance. This touches on the reason why premature micro-optimizations are so heavily looked down upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Braces have nothing to do with speed in a compiled language.

In cases where it is optional, it is just a style preference, albeit one with a higher potential for mistakes (e.g. Apple's faux pas).

All of these languages are compiled. The brace itself is not an instruction of any sort, it is simply a higher level syntactic element that you use to tell the compiler that a group of statements forms a coherent block of some kind. (The fact that it is a curly brace in many languages is probably more a matter of tradition than anything else.) It is similar in spirit to semicolons, parentheses, colons, etc. It is nothing more than a grammatical symbol used to help you express your program accurately to the compiler.

As far as I know there is no processor or virtual machine that has the equivalent of an `fyi_curly_brace_was_here` instruction.

This question is akin to asking if white-space or extra semicolons affect performance in compiled languages - these are all either optional formatting or necessary syntactic elements.

The reason we mention "compiled" languages is that certain interpreted languages, where the code is parsed as it is executed, could conceivably incur a modest speed penalty just due to parsing, but even in those types of languages, the effect would likely be completely negligible compared to whatever else the code itself is doing.

Comment: No problem. Just trying to bail the shipwreck of what I thought would have been a legitimate question worth having on the site.

Answer (score 3):

In compiled languages like C or C++, the existence or non-existence of brackets cannot make the actual program faster.

My guess: They just hacked it in faster without them.

Comment: I'd call JavaScript and PHP "C-like".

Comment: I mean technically, not visually.

Answer (score 2):

No. Compiled code is going to be the same.